# using python to create the constrains in abaqus

Tags: python, set, abaqus

Hi everyone i'm trying to create a model of beams and trusses in `abaqus` to simulate an experiment.

Since I have around 4000 unit cells I'm using a python script to do it.

At this moment I'm stuck trying to constrain the nodes. I need to use coupling to constrain the nodes from the different beams that are in the same coordinate.

I was thinking about create 2 sets of nodes for each coordinate and then input them on the coupling command. but until now I wasn't successful doing it.

```
myNodes = [] 

allNodes = mdb.models['Bias extension'].rootAssembly.nodes

for i in range (0, 5):
    for j in range (0, 2):
        x = j * 4.41941730
        y = i * 4.41941730
        delta = 1.0e-2
        xmin, ymin, zmin = x-delta, y-delta, 0-delta
        xmax, ymax, zmax = x+delta, y+delta, 0+delta
        myNodes[i] [j] = allNodes.getByBoundingBox(xmin, ymin, zmin, xmax, ymax, zmax)
```

I'm trying to first use this code to have my nodes to be able to divide them but it is not working

Thanks so much for the help

Comment: Without knowing what the exact problem is, this code won't work because `myNodes` is a list of length `0`  and you're trying to index it with `i` and `j`.

Answer (score 0):

When your code is entering the for loops, `myNodes` is a list of length `0`. 
Then you are trying to allocate a list of nodes to its `i` and `j` indices, which don't exist yet. You should get an outbound error.

In order for your code to work, you need to use the method `list.append()`:
`myNodes.append(allNodes.getByBoundingBox(xmin, ymin, zmin, xmax, ymax, zmax))`

That will store the selected nodes in a unidimensional list. But iIt looks like you'd like to store them in a two-dimensional matrix. There are two ways to achieve that:

1. A two-dimensional list:

   ```
   myNodes = []

   allNodes = mdb.models['Bias extension'].rootAssembly.nodes

   for i in range (0, 5):
       myNodes.append([])
       for j in range (0, 2):
           x = j * 4.41941730
           y = i * 4.41941730
           delta = 1.0e-2
           xmin, ymin, zmin = x-delta, y-delta, 0-delta
           xmax, ymax, zmax = x+delta, y+delta, 0+delta
           myNodes.append(allNodes.getByBoundingBox(xmin, ymin, zmin, xmax, ymax, zmax))
   ```

   Your output list will then look like that:
   `>>> myNodes
       [[listNodes00,listNodes01],[listNodes10,listNodes11],[listNodes20,listNodes21],[listNodes30,listNodes31],[listNodes40,listNodes41]]`
   `>>> myNodes[3][1]
       listNodes31`
2. The library [numPy](http://www.numpy.org/) and its [array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/arrays.html) structure.